# Sequence satisfying $ \lim_{n \to \infty}{x_{2n} + x_{2n + 1}} = M $, find $ \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{x_{2n}}{x_{2n + 1}}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that $ \left(x_{n}\right) $ is a sequence satisfying
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}{x_{2n} + x_{2n + 1}} = M \quad \mbox{and} \quad \lim_{n \to \infty}{x_{2n} + x_{2n - 1}} = N $$
with $ M \ne N $. Find
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{x_{2n}}{x_{2n + 1}}}. $$

---

At first, I tried to subtract two limits and got
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}{x_{2n + 1} - x_{2n - 1}} = M - N. $$
We also know that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{x_{2n}}{x_{2n + 1}}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{x_{2n} + x_{2n + 1}}{x_{2n + 1}} - 1}. $$
But since we don't know about the convergence of $ \left(x_{n}\right) $, I can't continue the argument.

I also tried using Stolz-Cesàro theorem, but since we don't know about the convergence and monotonicity of $ \left(x_{n}\right) $, we can't use it.

Could someone provide me with a helpful hint or strategy for tackling this problem? Thank you.

Note: The original problem used $ M = 315 $ and $ N = 2016 $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we put $u_n=x_{2n+1}+x_{2n}$ tends to $M$ and $v_n=x_{2n}+x_{2n-1}$ tends to $N$, the difference $u_n-v_n=x_{2n+1}-x_{2n-1}$ tends to $M-N$. By Stoltz-Cesaro, $\frac{x_{2n+1}}{n}$ tends to $M-N$ also. A similar argument shows that $\frac{x_{2n}}{n}$ tends to $N-M$. Can you finish from here ?